# How to read a text file and insert into databse in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Basically what i am trying to do is to insert content of a file to my database table.To be more clear ill explain it in details.I have a folder named "filedata" in which text files are uploaded.and the movement the files are uploaded to filedata folder i want to read those file,insert its content to database and delete that file from filedata folder.I am in confusion from where to start.I know php basics not much knowledge of it.So please anyone suggest me where to start.

Comment: Start from making a script that reads a normal file. Then you can move on from there.

Comment: What have you tried? We require code examples here, we do not just provide a complete solution for you. This question is too broad for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

it goes something like this first you read the file then you encode it into base64 then you insert it into database hope it helps

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$file_content=file_get_contents(path_of_file)
$data=base64_encode ( $file )
$sql = "insert into table 'tablename' values($data)"

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not going to write all the code you need to do for this but here's some pointers..

Getting all the files: **glob**(PATH), you can foreach through that, **basename**() will return the filename without path.
Deleting file: **unlink**(FILE)
Inserting data: **file_get_contents**() will grab the file (memory hog!)

Inserting data into a db.. make sure to have a blob column (binary) or largetext with base64 encoded.. depends what you need it for I guess..